# How can I upload this DataFrame into an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to upload this DataFrame to an excel file, but it keeps returning the error "could not broadcast input array from shape (50,56) into shape (50,)"
I am not sure how to change the shape though

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1&Season=2021-22&SeasonType=Playoffs"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')

response_data = pd.read_html(str(tables))


driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.quit()


new_storage = pd.DataFrame(response_data)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('2021 Data.xlsx')
new_storage.to_excel(writer, '2021')

writer.save()

read_file = pd.read_excel ("2021 Data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Answer (score 0):

What you did here:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('2021 Data.xlsx')
new_storage.to_excel(writer, '2021')
```

Is unclear, but doesn't work because it's like writing:

```
new_storage.to_excel(pd.ExcelWriter('2021 Data.xlsx'), '2021')
```

which doesn't mean anything.

**What you should do:**

```
new_storage = pd.DataFrame(response_data)


#a simple save:
new_storage.to_excel("output.xlsx")


#to read:
pd.read_excel('output.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

Comment: It is still giving me the error that "could not broadcast input array from shape (50,56) into shape (50,)"

Comment: Do "df.to_dict()" where "df" is the name of your dataframe and copy/paste the result in your question.